# Export Chart To Excel in ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

i'am trying to export data and chart from my ASP.net projet to Excel, i'am using the code below but i don't sucess to show the chart in Excel file i see only text

```
     public ActionResult ExportToExcel()
    {
        string imgPath2 = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) +                VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Content/" + tmpChartName);
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.xls;");
        StringWriter stringWrite = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);       
        string headerTable = @"<Table><tr><td>Begin</td><td><img src='" + imgPath2 + @"' /></td><td>end</td></tr></Table>";        
        Response.Output.Write(headerTable);
        Response.End();
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: What you're calling a chart is actually a table. And you're not actually creating an Excel file. You're creating an HTML file and serving it with an Excel MIME type and file extension. Instead, you need to use a library such as [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/), NPOI, or OpenXML SDK to create an actual Excel file.

Comment: Adding to what @mason has said, the method also returns `null`, which  returns, well, null

Comment: @DPac It doesn't need to return anything if it's writing directly to the response, so that will work. But it's not good. I'm assuming this is MVC since the method type says it returns an ActionResult. So it really should *not* write directly response, instead it should return a `FileResult`.

Answer (score 0):

Generally we do not need overkill/high fat libraries, instead deadly simple libraries/helper classes solves our problem

I found an helpers class that generates Excel 2007+ File [from here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/692092/A-free-Export-to-Excel-Csharp-class-using-OpenXML) and added some extension methods for converting `List` data to DataTable.

Although its documentaion has, need to sum up:

- Uncomment the first line to use with MVC/ASP.net projects.
- The class has a method in `#region HELPER_FUNCTIONS`

  ```
  public static DataTable ListToDataTable<T>(List<T> list)
  ```

but I use another solution which is an extension method stolen from Internet `ToDataTable`

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this List<T> list)

// ExtensionMethods.cs
static public class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static DataSet ToDataSet<T>(this IEnumerable<T> data)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.Tables.Add(data.ToDataTable());
        return ds;
    }

    public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this List<T> list)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        foreach (PropertyInfo info in typeof(T).GetProperties())
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(info.Name, GetNullableType(info.PropertyType)));
        }
        foreach (T t in list)
        {
            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            foreach (PropertyInfo info in typeof(T).GetProperties())
            {
                if (!IsNullableType(info.PropertyType))
                    row[info.Name] = info.GetValue(t, null);
                else
                    row[info.Name] = (info.GetValue(t, null) ?? DBNull.Value);
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        return dt;
    }
    private static Type GetNullableType(Type t)
    {
        Type returnType = t;
        if (t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(Nullable<>)))
        {
            returnType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(t);
        }
        return returnType;
    }
    private static bool IsNullableType(Type type)
    {
        return (type == typeof(string) ||
                type.IsArray ||
                (type.IsGenericType &&
                 type.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(Nullable<>))));
    }
}
```

**Finally usage is simple** put this code to Controller

```
    public void ExportToExcel()
    {
        using (var db = new EFDbContext())
        {
            var data = FetchDataAsList<MyDbEntityOrMvcModel>().ToDataTable();
            CreateExcelFile.CreateExcelDocument(data, "report.xlsx", System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response);
        }

    }
```

**Notice that** I used `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response` **not** `HttpContext.Current.Response`

**And call your action from view**

```
<a href="@Url.Action("GridExportToExcel", new { filter = Model.Filter})" class="fa fa-file-excel-o" />
```

Comment: this solution has the same problem and the image not appear.